# Extract keys values from string with space in values

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning about regex and attempting to extract from this string:

```
"a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 Request t=4,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f"
```

the key/values:

```
test1=0 
test2=1 
test3=2 
test4=3 
Request t=4
test6_r_a=5
```

I use this regex :

```
"\\p{Alnum}+ *=(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)+ "
```

which produces :

```
test1=0 
test2=1 
test3=2 
test4=3 test5 Request
```

The key,value pairs : `Request t=4,test6_r_a=5` are not matched.

What modification of regex is required to match the expected values ?

src :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExtractMatch {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String text = "a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 test5 Request t=4,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+ *=(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)+ ");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to allow the scenario where variable number of spaces can be within key, for example `"Request t"` or `"Request t d"`

update :

The string to be parsed is :

`"a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 t Request=4,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f"`

I've updated regex posted in answer by anubhava to use

`"\\w+=\\w+(?:\\h+\\d+)*\\b(?!=)"`

instead of :

`"\\w+=\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*\\b(?!=)"`

which produces :

```
test1=0
test2=1
test3=2
test4=3
Request=4
test6_r_a=5
```

But I'm expecting :

```
test1=0
test2=1
test3=2
test4=3
t Request=4
test6_r_a=5
```

src :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExtractMatch {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String text = "a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 t Request=4,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+=\\w+(?:\\h+\\d+)*\\b(?!=)");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saying: not everything should be solved regular expressions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for matching all `kep=value` pairs:

```sh
\w+(?:\h+\w+)*=\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TJ0uLJ/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters as key start word
- `(?:\h+\w+)*`: Match space separated 0 or more words
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters

**Code:**

```
final String text = "a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 t Request=4,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*=\\w+");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: thank you, I omitted a character in the string I'm attempting to parse. The string is "a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 test5 t Request=4,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f";  apologies for this, I've updated the question.

Comment: the question update shows the correct input.

Comment: ok try this regex: `\w+(?:\h+\w+)*=\w+` on updated sample

Answer (score 1):

Using `\p{Alnum}` does not match an underscore.

You might use matching word characters like:

```
\w+(?:\h+\w+)*=\w+
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\h+\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `=` Match literally
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK1UBW/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/0W6KVe)

```
final String text = "a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 t Request=4,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)*=\\w+");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output

```
test1=0
test2=1
test3=2
test4=3
t Request=4
test6_r_a=5
```

---

Or a version with `\p{Alnum}` and an undercore in a character class:

```
[\p{Alnum}_]+(?:\h+[\p{Alnum}_]+)*=[\p{Alnum}_]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WOaX6/1)

Answer (score 1):

Used regex:

```
"(?<=,|\\W)([^,]+?=\\w+)"
```

It is also supporting match like "Request t d".

Read about regex constructs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Testbench and regex in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String input = "a,b,c,test1=0 test2=1 test3=2 test4=3 Request t=4 Request t d=42,test6_r_a=5,d,e,f";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=,|\\W)([^,]+?=\\w+)").matcher(input);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.printf("'%s'%n", matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'test1=0'
'test2=1'
'test3=2'
'test4=3'
'Request t=4'
'Request t d=42'
'test6_r_a=5'
```